# Which of the impedance values below represent an pasive dipole that absorbs both active power P and reactive power Q, and why?

Tags: dipole

I stumbled upon this exercise and I can't find anything in my notes regarding to this notion where it absorbs both kind of powers. You guys might have any ideas?

These are the impedance values:

Z1 = 2-3j [Ohm]

Z2 = 3 [Ohm]

Z3 = 2+3j [Ohm]

Z4 = +2j [Ohm].

I also need to justify theoretically. Looking forward to hearing your knowledge

Comment: This looks very much like a homework problem with no work shown. Also, here, have a Ω.

Comment: @Felthry As I said, I merely needed some theory notions, in order to solve it myself. I guess it's easier to complain than to help, huh?

Comment: It's less that helping is hard and more that it's against the site rules.